# How do you get default system colors in Firemonkey?

Tags: delphi, colors, styles, firemonkey, delphi-xe5

In FireMonkey, how do you get system colours for common interface elements?

For example, in the VCL you would use one of the color constants (eg [`clWindow`, `clBtnFace`, `clMenu`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/Colors_in_VCL#System_Colors) for the window, button and menu colours.) Or, you might use the [style API's `GetSystemColor`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/Vcl.Themes.TCustomStyleServices.GetSystemColor) if using custom styles.

However FireMonkey is cross-platform and doesn't have equivalent constants, or items exposed in its style system. How do you get these or similar values in a cross-platform manner?

Comment: I assume you need this cross-platform (you don't say), eg to get the button color for Android or iOS or Windows or OSX... Is that the case, or is it Windows only? (I rewrote your question since it was getting downvoted, and at the end included my cross-platform assumption.) If it is Windows only, you can convert the VCL system colours to RGB, and then to FMX colours. I can add this with more details as an answer if you wish.

Comment: Thanks, osx+win desktop yet, I know the winapi/vcl side. I wanted to create a treeview with different colored items depending on the level. I guess I can't do it from source code only like in VCL, need to use style resources and a lot of IDE clicking...

Answer (score 3):

FireMonkey does not have or use any system-defined colors, colors are explicit RGBA values.  FireMonkey has color constants, but they are fixed RGBA values, not resolved by the OS at runtime.  In short, system-defined colors are a Windows-specific feature of VCL only, not available in FireMonkey.